# How to use Flurl with instance of HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

Let's say I have an instance of `HttpClient` which is already configured. And now I want to use it for Flurl requests. I'd like to do something like this:

```cs
var poco = await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<POCO>();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try? What happened? Did you get errors? Compile time or runtime?

Comment: Most common usage case of Flurl is calling extension method on string url, not on already existing instance of `HttpClient`. Flurl handles creation of `HttpClient` instance on its own. Hence my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure...

```
var flurlClient = new FlurlClient(httpClient);
var poco = await flurlClient.Request(url).GetJsonAsync<POCO>();
```